# Remembering results from last function call?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, class

I was recently given a coding challenge as part of a job interview, and the problem is pretty simple. Write a class that has two functions: (1) `allocate(some_string)`, which returns a string based on its parameter, except its return value is the parameter plus a number. For example, calling `allocate("apple")` will return `apple1`, calling it again will return `apple2`, and so on. (2) `deallocate(some_string)` takes in a parameter and makes that string available again. Meaning If I call deallocate("apple1") and then call `allocate("apple")` again, `allocate` would give me back `apple1`.

Here is my code:

```
class Tracker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.returned_host_names = set()
        self.host_type_so_far = set()

    def allocate(self, host_type):
        self.counter = 0
        self.host_type_so_far.add(host_type)
        if host_type in self.host_type_so_far:
            self.counter+=1
        while True:
            maybe_hostname = host_type + str(self.counter)
            if maybe_hostname not in self.returned_host_names:
                self.returned_host_names.add(maybe_hostname)
                print(self.returned_host_names)
                return maybe_hostname
            else: 
                self.counter+=1

    def deallocate(self, hostname):
        if hostname in self.returned_host_names:
            self.returned_host_names.remove(hostname)
```

The code actually doesn't come with `__init__`; that's something I added myself. I'm currently using the two sets to remember what has been returned and then deallocate to remove them from the sets. My question is since `__init__` isn't given, is there a different way for me to write allocate? My initial thought was to initialize the two sets in `allocate()` but obviously that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize `self.returned_host_names` and `self.host_type_so_far` inside the `allocate` method instead by checking if the object already has the attribute or not using `hasattr`. And to prevent the `deallocate` method from raising an exception due to an uninitialized `self.returned_host_names` if it's called before `allocate`, you can add a `try-except` block around it:

```
class Tracker:
    def allocate(self, host_type):
        if not hasattr(self, 'returned_host_names'):
            self.returned_host_names = set()
            self.host_type_so_far = set()
        self.counter = 0
        self.host_type_so_far.add(host_type)
        if host_type in self.host_type_so_far:
            self.counter+=1
        while True:
            maybe_hostname = host_type + str(self.counter)
            if maybe_hostname not in self.returned_host_names:
                self.returned_host_names.add(maybe_hostname)
                print(self.returned_host_names)
                return maybe_hostname
            else:
                self.counter+=1

    def deallocate(self, hostname):
        try:
            if hostname in self.returned_host_names:
                self.returned_host_names.remove(hostname)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
```

Note that it is not a good practice to initialize instance attributes outside the `__init__` method and I highly doubt that the interviewer really doesn't want you to write your own `__init__` method even if you are not provided with one. The above is just an example of how you can make it work but the approach should not be used in any production code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't think of one off the top of my head, but do you think there's another way to tackle the problem without using sets like I did?